# How to print SQLSTATE in messages

Tags: postgresql

I want to print the sqlstate and sql message error when for example there's a null violation:

```
    EXCEPTION WHEN not_null_violation THEN
    narticlesp:=0;
     raise notice 'Got exception: state: %, message: %', SQLSTATE, SQLERRM;
```

But the code above doesn't show the message or stop the excecution.

The next one, put '0' to all the rows in the variable narticlesp and still doens't show the message:

```
    GET DIAGNOSTICS v_msg=PG_CONTEXT;
        raise notice ' %',  v_msg;
        narticlesp:=0;
        END;
```

And this one, is functional. But i don't know how to put the sqlstate and sql message error

```
IF ncommentsp IS NULL THEN 
    RAISE NOTICE 'User have no commments %: ', registro.user_code;
    ncommentsp:=0; 
    END IF;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RAISE EXCEPTION instead of RAISE NOTICE

In your case,

```
 EXCEPTION WHEN not_null_violation THEN
    narticlesp:=0;
     raise **exception** 'Got exception: state: %, message: %', SQLSTATE, SQLERRM;
```

Comment: Thank you, I was using this in the wrong order and I put it at the end and it worked.